# how to change xamarin.ios version in visual studio 2022 for mac

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I have a macbook pro 2015 and I can't update mac oS. But I accidentally updated the visual studio 2022 xamarin.iOS package and now visual studio requires me to update Xcode to version 14.3, and my maximum Xcode update version is 14.1. Visual Studio gives me the following errors:

`/Users/Vladimir/Projects/test/Test/Test.iOS/MTOUCH: Warning MT0079: The recommended Xcode version for Xamarin.iOS 16.4.0 is Xcode 14.3 or later. The current Xcode version (found in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer) is 14.1. (MT0079) (Test.iOS)`

`/Users/Vladimir/Projects/test/Test/Test.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT0180: This version of Xamarin.iOS requires the iOS 16.4 SDK (shipped with Xcode 14.3). Either upgrade Xcode to get the required header files or set the managed linker behaviour to Link Framework SDKs Only in your project's iOS Build Options > Linker Behavior (to try to avoid the new APIs). (MT0180) (Test.iOS)`

but as I said, I have no way to update Xcode, so it remains only to return an older version of xamarin.iOS

I looked in the project settings, but I didn't find anything

Comment: delete VS and install an older version

Comment: I need visual studio 2022, but with a different version of xamarin.iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Mac isn’t compatible with Ventura 13, you need to downgrade to the older Xamarin.iOS https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/cc89cd8e-a615-4d98-8783-8b932996a8fd/8be868ae2c77e0054acb14b1b111dbbb/xamarin.ios-16.2.0.6.pkg

Here we can find a solve for downgrade Xamarin.iOS

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin-16406-requires-XCode-143-bit/10353330

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.